# ¿Alguien sabe como obtener el código abierto o libre de Android para Java

Tags: android

He estado buscando una respuesta a mi anteriores preguntas y me dado cuenta que estas preguntas solo se podrán resolver investigando profundada mente en el tema por eso he creado esta pregunta para saber si existe algún código abierto o libre de android para java para el uso de programadores. Específicamente lo que necesito investigar con ese código es el sistema de instalado de apk y ejecución de app (Creo que esto se lleva acabo con ART o DALVIK). Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí. Cuando instalas Android Studio también se instala el SDK Manager y ahí seleccionas la opción de Sources (perdón pero no estoy seguro de la palabra exacta en la versión en español):

[image: Sources]

Una vez instalado, dirígete al directorio raíz del SDK y después a `sources/android-X/android` donde X=API deseado. Ahí encontrarás el código fuente.

Dalvik y ART son los runtimes de Java especiales para Android. Dalvik es KitKat hacia abajo y ART de Lollipop hacia arriba.

Comment: Muchas Gracias su respuesta me ha ayudado a extender mi búsqueda